# Trying to connect Ruby on Rails with PostgresSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3

Everytime, I tried to create a user. This is what it shows:

> sudo -u postgres createuser jenn -s

[image]

```
$ psql --version
Warning: No existing cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package

$ pg_config --version PostgreSQL 14.6
(Ubuntu 14.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
```

When I tried to do this:

```
$ sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

It shows this on the terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libpq5 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable
           Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
postgresql-15 : Depends: postgresql-client-15 but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
                Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable
                Depends: libllvm6.0 (>= 1:6.0~svn298832-1~) but it is not installable
                Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
                Recommends: sysstat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Versions:

[image]

My rails is running fine on the localhost. I just can't connect it with postgresql

How do I fix this error?

I originally followed this tutorial: gorails.com/setup/windows/10#final-steps

I started having problems on this part:

```
rails new myapp -d postgresql
```

Thereafter I tried it with this part:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-20-04#prerequisites

After entering this on the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

**UPDATE**

```
 sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Results:

```
    Hit:1 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/bionic-pgdg/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libpq-dev libpq5
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgrade
```

After that:

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

Results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq5 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable
          Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
 postgresql-15 : Depends: postgresql-client-15 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libllvm6.0 (>= 1:6.0~svn298832-1~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sysstat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


sudo uname -a
```

Results:
Linux DESKTOP-KDG1T61 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Nov 23 01:01:46 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
cat /etc/os-release


PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text rather than images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: And maybe edit out the commands that didn’t work or aren’t relevant.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hello, I have already edited it

Comment: You deleted the picture of formatted text with the error from Ruby that indicated the PG user didn’t exist. Is your PG running? Have you configured it correctly in the Rails config? It seems like a PG and/or Rails “Getting Started” tutorial would be the best first approach.

Comment: @DaveNewton how can I check it? I did follow the tutorial for this: https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#final-steps I started having problems on this part: `rails new myapp -d postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you can't install PostgreSQL itself.
Try to:

1. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. That will update your packages
2. `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`

PostgreSQL should be installed properly after that. If it is not, provide me the output of the previous command and the next commands:

1. `sudo uname -a`
2. `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: I tried the first, however, it will fail on `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt install libldap`